# window.open doesn't Open a Window

Tags: javascript, window.open

The following markup is generated by my ASP.NET MVC page.

```
<button onclick="window.open='/Client/ReleaseForm';" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
    View/Print Release Form
</button>
```

However, clicking the button has no effect. No window is opened, no new tabs are opened, and no errors are shown in the console of my Chrome browser.

I know there are pop-up blockers, but I had got the impression that this worked as long as it was in response to a user action (such as clicking the button).

Can anyone tell me how I can display content in a new window?

Comment: @SecondRikudo: Yes, what about it?

Comment: `window.open` is a **function** - `window.open("/Client/ReleaseForm")`

Comment: @Pointy: Well dang, I tried that and got an error.

Comment: @JonathanWood it doesn't really have anything to do with your question, but what the hell is an MVC page?

Comment: @JonathanWood What error?

Comment: @Pointy: VM238:2 Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function

Comment: @SecondRikudo: That's a page created using Microsoft's ASP.NET MVC. The markup I write is different than what is shown, but that's the HTML that gets rendered.

Comment: Well you wouldn't get that error if the event handler attribute looked like what I posted in the comment.

Comment: @JonathanWood I edited that in, in the world outside of .NET, MVC has a radically different meaning.

Comment: @Pointy: I'm typing `window.open('/Client/ReleaseForm')` in the console window of my Chrome browser and I get that error. Will try in script.

Comment: @JonathanWood no repro, I get a new tab as expected.

Comment: @JonathanWood if your broken "click" handler has already run, then you've overwritten the normal value of `window.open` with a string. Try in a freshly-loaded page.

Comment: @Pointy: Ha, good observation. I didn't think of that. Anyway, working now. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure [`window.open`](http://devdocs.io/dom/window.open) is a function, so you want:

```
window.open('/Client/ReleaseForm');
```

Also, it's probably even better to set an event handler in JavaScript code and not inline.

```
<button id="print" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
    View/Print Release Form
</button>

<!-- Elsewhere, in a JS file -->

document.getElementById('print')
    .addEventListener('click', function viewOrPrintReleaseForm() {
        window.open('/Client/ReleaseForm');
    });
```

Comment: Yeah, this is working now. I tried typing `window.open('/Client/ReleaseForm')` in the browser (Chrome) and got the error "Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function". Not sure what happened there but it threw me off. I added a handler using jQuery and it works as expected.